# jQuery removeClass() not working with next()

Tags: jquery, slideshow

Maybe it is a stupid question but I have a problem with `removeClass()` method

I am working with a slideshow which works automatically

This is my slide div:

```
<div class="imageSlide">
  <figure>
    <img class="Introduction img-fluid"  src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/digitaltrends-uploads-prod/2016/01/headphones-man-listening-to-music-pandora-spotify-apple-music-cur-groove-play-google.jpg">
    <figcaption class="Introduction">If you are looking for some awesome music, LovingMusic.com is for you! We have more than 50000 musics!</figcaption>
    <img class="Introduction img-fluid invisible" src="http://blog.goeventz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/music-festivals.jpg">
    <figcaption class="Introduction">We have a lot of events for you!</figcaption>
    <img class="Introduction img-fluid invisible" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/40815/youth-active-jump-happy-40815.jpeg">
    <figcaption class="Introduction">Join our community and buy musics to win the prize</figcaption>
  </figure>             
  <input type="radio" name="ImageList" class="ImageList" checked><input type="radio" name="ImageList" class="ImageList"><input type="radio" name="ImageList" class="ImageList">
</div>
```

This is a slideshow javascript script:

```
var imageIndex =0;
setInterval(imageSlide, 3000);

function imageSlide(){
  var $img =$('img.Introduction');
  var $radioBox = $('input[class="Introduction"]');
  if(imageIndex<$img.length){
    $img.addClass('invisible');
    $img.next('.invisible').removeClass('invisible');
    imageIndex = imageIndex +1;
    console.log(imageIndex);//added to check if counting and if loop works correctly
  }
  if(imageIndex == $img.length)
    imageIndex =0;
}
```

problem is method `removeClass()` doesn't work.
According to my css style,

```
img.Introduction{
  position: relative;
  height: 40vh;
  width: 40vw;
  transition: filter 0.5s;
}

img.Introduction:hover{
  filter: brightness(60%);
  -webkit-filter: brightness(60%);
  -ms-filter: brightness(60%);
  -moz-filter: brightness(60%);
  -o-filter: brightness(60%);   
 }

 img.invisible{
   display: none;
 }
```

`img` tag which has Introduction class doesn't have any css display style. 
But my web browser just removes first image and doesn't show second image. Why?

Comment: @Taplar Do you mean var $img =$('img.Introduction:not(.invisible)'); ? Tried that. Did not work

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
  var $images = $('img.Introduction');
  var $imageList = $('.ImageList');
  
  setInterval(function(){
    //get the one image that is visible
    var $current = $images.not('.invisible');
    //get the image at the next index, but mod for the images length so it will wrap back to 0
    var $next = $images.eq( ($images.index($current) + 1) % $images.length );
    //hide the current image
    $current.addClass('invisible');
    //show the next image
    $next.removeClass('invisible');
    //adjust the radio buttons at the bottom
    $imageList.eq($images.index($next)).prop('checked', true);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
img.Introduction {
  position: relative;
  height: 40vh;
  width: 40vw;
  transition: filter 0.5s;
}

img.Introduction:hover {
  filter: brightness(60%);
  -webkit-filter: brightness(60%);
  -ms-filter: brightness(60%);
  -moz-filter: brightness(60%);
  -o-filter: brightness(60%);
}

img.invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imageSlide">
  <figure>
    <img class="Introduction img-fluid" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/digitaltrends-uploads-prod/2016/01/headphones-man-listening-to-music-pandora-spotify-apple-music-cur-groove-play-google.jpg">
    <figcaption class="Introduction">If you are looking for some awesome music, LovingMusic.com is for you! We have more than 50000 musics!</figcaption>
    <img class="Introduction img-fluid invisible" src="http://blog.goeventz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/music-festivals.jpg">
    <figcaption class="Introduction">We have a lot of events for you!</figcaption>
    <img class="Introduction img-fluid invisible" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/40815/youth-active-jump-happy-40815.jpeg">
    <figcaption class="Introduction">Join our community and buy musics to win the prize</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <input type="radio" name="ImageList" class="ImageList" checked><input type="radio" name="ImageList" class="ImageList"><input type="radio" name="ImageList" class="ImageList">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked fine!

Comment: Please add some explanation, not just a code dump. What was wrong in the question, and how you fixed it.

Comment: The code is commented.  That is hardly a code dump. @Barmar